# Use of Undefined Constant - assumed id

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel

I am new to angularjs and am having some trouble implementing a simple checklist.

```
<html lang="en" ng-app>
<body>
<div ng-controller="IdController" class="id-contain">

<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="id in ids">{{ id.body }}</li>
</ul>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and in my `main.js` I have

```
function IdController($scope) {
$scope.id = [
    { body: 'some' },
    { body: 'boiler' },
    { body: 'plate' }
];
}
```

However, when I load the page, i get `Use of undefined constant id - assumed 'id'` Any ideas on where I could have gone wrong?

Edit: I have adjusted the name in the controller from `$scope.id` to `$scope.ids` to no avail and when I change the {{}} to [[]] it loads [[ id.body ]] 3 times, but not the value. When I run it with {{}} it is giving me the same error and is parsed as `<?php echo id.body; ?>`

Comment: perhaps it is somewhere in the php code?

Comment: need to find and replace some `id` to `$id` in your PHP :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a problem with blade, you can change laravel's config for blade template token from {{}} to something else like [[]]

```
Blade::setContentTags('[[', ']]');
Blade::setEscapedContentTags('[[[', ']]]');
```

Plus, in your angularjs code you should rename `$scope.id` to `$scope.ids` in your controller

**UPDATE** Blade tokens

**EDIT** OR you can override angular's tags delimiters

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mhULx/1/)

**HTML**:

```
<div ng-app="main">
        <div ng-controller="IdController" class="id-contain">
        <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="id in ids">[[id.body]]</li>
            </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**:

```
angular.module('main', [])
.config(function ($interpolateProvider) {
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[');
    $interpolateProvider.endSymbol(']]');
})
.controller('IdController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.ids = [
        { body: 'some' },
        { body: 'boiler' },
        { body: 'plate' }
    ];
});
```

Comment: I have adjusted the name in the controller from `$scope.id` to `$scope.ids` to no avail and when I change the {{}} to [[]] it loads [[ id.body ]] 3 times, but not the value. When I run it with {{}} it is giving me the same error and is parsed as `<?php echo id.body; ?>`

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't very clear, I was talking about laravel's config for `Blade::setContentTags('[[', ']]');
Blade::setEscapedContentTags('[[[', ']]]');`

Comment: I am not sure that is the error, because when I use vanilla PHP `<?php echo skill.body; ?>` instead, I still get the same error :/

Comment: There seems to be a confusion here, when you do `echo skill.body` you are trying to concatenate two constants (probably undefined) skill and body which is probably not what you want

Comment: hmm, how would you echo out the contents of the array in controller?

Comment: Maybe we should should talk here: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50553/use-of-undefined-constant-assumed-id

Answer (score 13):

> Since many JavaScript frameworks also use "curly" braces to indicate a given expression should be displayed in the browser, you may use the @ symbol to inform the Blade rendering engine an expression should remain untouched.
> https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks

Use `@`before your angular `{{}}` blocks:

Your code would be like:

```
    <html lang="en" ng-app>
    <body>
    <div ng-controller="IdController" class="id-contain">
    
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="id in ids"> @{{ id.body }} </li>
    </ul>
    
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: this would not be like ignoring the warnings ??

Comment: No. Since many JavaScript frameworks also use "curly" braces to indicate a given expression should be displayed in the browser, you may use the @ symbol to inform the Blade rendering engine an expression should remain untouched. https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#blade-and-javascript-frameworks

Answer (score 0):

You html is parsed with the blade parser, if you dont need this page to be parsed with blade parser rename your file from `myfield.blade.php` to `myfile.php`